# Swift Protocol Extension Where Self Is Subclass

Tags: swift, protocols, superclass

Is it possible to implement a protocol or protocol extension that specifies that the protocol will only be used for classes & that those classes have super classes ?

If so, can I leverage this to have a function that iterates down through a class's superclasses to gather all of the data they each is storing one common variable ?

In other words, in the example below is it possible to create an extension that does what the second BaseType extension pseudocode is trying to do such that at the end `allVals = ["core", "middle", "top"]` ?

```
import Foundation

protocol BaseType: class {
  var data: [String] { get }
  var all: [String] { get }
}

extension BaseType {
  var all: [String] {
    return data
  }
}

// Is the intent of this extension realistic? 
extension BaseType where Self.super is BaseType {
  var all: [String] {
    return data + super.all
  }
}

class CoreDT: BaseType {
  var core: String = "core"
  var data: [String] { return [core] }
}


class MiddleDT: CoreDT {
  var middle: String = "middle"
  override var data: [String] { return [middle] }
}

class TopDT: MiddleDT {
  var top: String = "top"
  override var data: [String] { return [top] }
}

let allVals = TopDT().all

print(allVals)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The simple answer is:

You cannot achieve this.

#### The detailed one:

You can only achieve the functionality to work with superclass inside protocol by implementing NSObjectProtocol above it. But then, the problem with the bridged functions from Objective C to Swift will appear. The solution will be tomake the protocol an @objc protocol, but then you will not be able to extend it with default implementation.